# How does one do research in any field?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education, reference-works

I have started my PhD in this academic year.The topic which I have been given to work on is Spectral Graph Theory.

As I have just completed my Master's Course which was  very straight forward for me as I  only had to complete the stipulated syllabus and do the  problems assigned to me,I am in a difficult position now.

I don't understand what should I do,neither do I understand the only book I found in the internet and the standard reference on Spectral Graph Theory,the book *Spectra of Graphs-Brouwer,Haemers*.

I have $3$ and a half years avaliable and already I have lost $6$ months soing practically nothing.

Also there are not enough materials available in this field.

Questions that need to be answered are:

1.How do people select courses for their research?

2.What are the prerequisites for solving problems in this field?

Talking to my advisor is also a distant dream.Firstly he told me that it is not school that he will tell me what to read and what not and secondly he is busy with arranging  PhD entrance exams and some of his personal problems.

Above all one question is really taking my sleep away **How does one do research in any field?**

**Are there any suitable ways to tackle this sort of disappointment?**

There is so much information in this field and so many branches that I am getting confused.

**Please don't close this question.I really need some sort of advice**

Comment: "Talking to my advisor is also not possible." --> that's a huge problem, right? Isn't he supposed to "advise" you?

Comment: I edited the question@fonfonx

Comment: "Talking to my advisor is also a distant dream. Firstly he told me that it is not school that he will tell me what to read and what not and secondly he is busy with arranging PhD entrance exams and some of his personal problems. He told not to approach him with these matters." If this is the case and not hyperbole, **you need to leave right away**: find another advisor as soon as possible.

Comment: Noah Schweber is absolutely right.  Get out from under the guy ASAP!!! Your life depends on it!

Comment: @NoahSchweber;He told me that he also did his PhD in this way;His(My advisor's) advisor didn't know anything about his research field but still he completed his Phd on his own without any help from his advisor in just $4$ years

Comment: Get a better supervisor!

Comment: "I have started my PhD in this academic year.The topic which I have been given to work on is Spectral Graph Theory." You're _given_ topics to work on??? I never knew that's how PhD's work. I thought students are free to study what they're interested in.

Comment: This is probably a better question for academia.stackexchange.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122;there is no faculty where I am interested in my university;so I was assigned to him

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Yes, that's another seeming red flag. Suggesting specific questions to investigate is normal, but it sounds more like the advisor told the student what field to work in, which is not.

Comment: @layman;I never studied lecture notes;I always studied books as I knew that I will be going for a PhD

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be assigned a concrete question of research? Just studying Spectral Graph Theory hoping to discover something that no one else has done seems to be a dead end: a situation as made for a performance neurosis!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"How does one do research in any field?" You are not expected to know how to answer that question at the start of a PhD program, and an advisor's primary job is to guide you through that process. The commenters are right that this is an extremely concerning situation that you should take seriously. Seek another advisor immediately.